# How to solve authentication problems in facebook

Tags: json, facebook, authentication, sdk, token

I am creating an application that until yesterday seemed to work, but this morning, performing a function as I always do, it turns out this message:
"Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. Thrown in ../base_facebook.php on line 1254"
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some code would be helpful for figuring out what's going on (e.g. what APIs you are accessing, etc.). :)

Comment: index.php
"
<?php
 require_once 'appinclude.php';
 require_once 'home.php';
?>
"

Comment: appinclude.php
<?php
$config['appId']=.
$config['secret']=.
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user = $facebook->getUser();           
$canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/...";
$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
. $appapikey . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
   list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
echo("<script> top.location.href='". $auth_url . "'</script>");
}
?>
"

Comment: you really need to inclue your code in the question, this error can happen for many reasons and it´s not a good idea to put code in a comment. no syntax highlighting, no code indentation, ...

Comment: I just found out that the problem is only when using the application with Internet Explorer and Chrome; 

no problem if I use Firefox; 

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you Try to clean the cookies and cache from your firefox browser and try to execute your application once again...and check if you are app works in firefox this time...

Comment: I cleared all...nothing


IMPORTANT: I have this problem ONLY IF use the application with Internet Explorer and Chrome; no problem if I use Firefox; 

where is the problem?